# Windows Form + database (Sql Server)+ Windows Mobile Application

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, windows-mobile, windows-server-2008

I am student and i am doing project of Order Accepting system for five star hotels.Scenario is Waiter will accept order using Window Mobile which is Connected to WiFi present in hotel.I want to communicate to database(Sql Server) present on My Machine (Computer present in kitchen) through WiFi and Add order into table present inside database. This should notify my application present on Compter and should print order. After completion of Order Application from kitchen will notify to waiter about completion.
      My problem is How to Communicate with database present on Remote computer using WiFi from windows Mobile. I have other ideas to fulfil my requirment but still is It Possible !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to read-up on [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Obviously the compact edition of the database does not have all the functionality of the full version that will be running on the remote machine.  Depending on what information will be stored on the mobile device you may not need a database on the device at all.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur concern,
This is the one way we can go for that , But is there any way to fire query on remote server from Mobile Device (windows Mobile or Any other ) ?

Comment: Don't think so much about actual database queries, the remote machine will provide a service, so you could ask the remote for things like GetWineList, GetDishOfDay.  You would send data back like CreateDrinksOrder, CreateMainOrder.  All these methods will be passing back and forwards business objects.

Comment: In this scenario my project will divided into three parts , 
1. Mobile device application
2. WCF service 
3. Windows Application which will take care of printing order and bills 

Is it So ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.  I think you are too fixated on the WiFi part.  There are certain considerations you need to take into account due to the unreliable network conditions, but beyond that it isn't any different that developing the application on a wired network.

Comment: As my system requires a mobile entity (waiter) , We can't take into considerations that device will be conneced through wired Network.

Comment: If you read my answer, I stated that.  You obviously misunderstood my statements.  You must take into consideration that you will not have a reliable connection; but the tools used will be the same as developing any other app.  You can still use ADO.Net to connect to SqlServer (or any other db).  You can still use WCF or ASP.Net Web Services to connect to any server.

Comment: Hi , 
I have completely changed Idea of My project , Its like 
I will have Website hosted on My Local IIS server for hotel .
I will set login for waiters , They will perform all possible operations using website from their devices ( Any wifi enabled device ) , And operations will be performed on Database by website and My Windows Application will have SqlDependency on database. so it can listen to changes in database and will take appropriate action . 

Is is the sophisticated way ????
plz tell me , coz i am going to start soon...